# Setting up Web Server database in AWS - Having trouble understanding dbinfo.inc file portion of instructions

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been following the directions in this link to setup MySQL in my EC2 Instance:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html

I am having difficulty inputting the required data into the dbinfo.inc file with the `DB_server` and `DB_Database` as the directions are not clear in the link. For `DB_SERVER` it says to input the db instance endpoint.

I did create the endpoint but I don't know what to input in `'db_instance_endpoint'`. Should I input the Name, Endpoint ID, or Service Name of the endpoint?

I did create a database, but I don't know what to input in place of the `'sample'` database. Do I input the databases DB Identifier or just leave as `'sample'`?

Do I just input the master password of the database and input the Databases master password I created when creating the database.

Keep in mind I have not created the `'tutorial_user'` account or the `'sample'` database.

I am new to MySQL so I am not sure if the SamplePage.php, in the link I posted above, creates the 'sample' database and 'tutorial_user' or is this something I need to do prior to filling out the dbinfo.inc.

```
<?php
 
define('DB_SERVER', 'db_instance_endpoint');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'tutorial_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'master password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'sample');
 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I input the Name, Endpoint ID, or Service Name of the endpoint?

Its full endpoint url, such as:

```
database-3.cet1e6zsz0ag.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

> I did create a database, but I don't know what to input in place of the 'sample' database.

If you created a default database when creating the RDS, you put the value from `DB Name` in `Configuration` tab of your RDS.

> Do I just input the master password of the database and input the Databases master password I created when creating the database.

Yes, for the initial connection you need master account and `admin` user (default user unless you changed it). Once you connect for the first time, you can create additional users with restricted privileges.

> Keep in mind I have not created the 'tutorial_user' account or the 'sample' database.

After initial connection, you can create them using regular SQL commands, like you would on your local database.

Therefore, if you followed [the link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateDBInstance.html) from the tutorial, your file could look something like below:

```
<?php
 
define('DB_SERVER', 'database-3.cet1e6zsz0ag.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'tutorial_user'); # master user
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'master password');
define('DB_DATABASE', ' sample'); # if created when setting up RDS. if not skip this
 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, with your help @Marcin I was able to verify connection.

Comment: @jastanle84 No problem. If the answer was helpful its accepted would be appreciated.